# Есть несколько одинаковых списков, если в одном выбираю значение - как это значение скрывать в других списках?

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

Есть несколько списков одинаковых.

```
<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я в первом выбирал например первое значение это значение в других списках ставало `disabled`, или скрывалось.
А если я убираю активность с опции которую выбрал, то во всех селектах появлялся эта опция для выбора.

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Ты сам только что логику расписал в вопросе. Что именно не получается?

Comment: Пробовал вешать change на select, но там можно выбрать только те которые selected опции. А нужно как-то повесить change на конкретный option, и отслеживать его... Может какое-то простое решение есть, чтобы костыли не писать...

Comment: Нет, выбирать у select можно не только selected. ты можешь спокойно указать порядковый номер option. отслеживать, если он равен, например 1, то делать манипуляции.. типа такого `$('select[name=name]:eq(0) option:eq(1)');`.... также ты можешь смотреть на его значение и по нему ориентироваться...то есть если при change в select'e равно отслеживаемому - делаем действия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вот так работает.

```js
$('.change').on('change',function() {
      $(this).children('option').each(function(){
      var options = $('.change option[value='+$(this).val()+']').not(this);
      if($(this).is(':selected')) {
        $(options).prop('disabled',true);
        $(options).prop('selected',false);
      } else {
        $(options).prop('disabled',false);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, но не до конца работает. Возьму на вооружение и немного допилю. Спасибо

Comment: Да, тоже увидел баг: ранее недоступные опции у меня разблокируются  чаще, чем надо и нужно доп. условие. Вы правы.

Comment: Нужно добавить проверку на if (!option.is(':disabled')) ) только. А так взял Ваш вариант полностью, благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что нужно что-то такое:

```js
let trackingSelect = 'select[name=name]:eq(0)';

$(document).on('change', trackingSelect, function(){ 
  let optionValue = this.selectedIndex == 0 ? 'option[value="' + $(this).val()  + '"]' : 'option[value]';
  let propFlag = this.selectedIndex == 0 ? true : false;     
  $('select[name=name]').not(trackingSelect).find(optionValue).prop('disabled', propFlag);        
});

/*
$(document).on('change', trackingSelect, function(){ 
  let optionValue = 'option[value]';
  let propFlag = false;   
  
  if (this.selectedIndex == 0) {
    optionValue = 'option[value="' + $(this).val()  + '"]';
    propFlag = true;
  }
  $('select[name=name]').not(trackingSelect).find(optionValue).prop('disabled', propFlag);        
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
<option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>
```

Где `select[name=name]:eq(0)` указывает на первый `select`, `this.selectedIndex == 0` указывает на первый `option` в данном `select'е` (при желании - изменить)

Однако в данном случае, если человек ткнет что-то в других селектах, а потом в первом выберет первый - то нужно предупредить юзера, чтоб перевыбрал значения

Answer (score 1):

Решение задачи:

```js
$('.change').on('change', function() {
  $(this).children('option').each(function() {
    var option = $(this),
      options = $('.change option[value=' + option.val() + ']').not(this);

    if (!option.is(':disabled')) {
      if (option.is(':selected')) {
        $(options).prop('disabled', true);
        $(options).prop('selected', false);
      } else {
        $(options).prop('disabled', false);
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
<option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>

<select name="name" multiple="true" class="change">
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
    <option value="3">Text3</option>
</select>
```